# extrude circle and spin and scale (Think of a cone but in the shape of a donut)

Tags: python

I am trying to make an addon that can generate half a donut (between 1 and 360 degrees) from a circle but I would like the "extrusion" to be scaled down.

[image]

I tried `bmesh.ops.spin` and `bmesh.ops.scale` but that only scales the last circle of vertices and not all of them

I also tried extrude / scale and spin but that makes the whole extruded circle the same size after the spin.

I also tried `bridge_edge_loop` with 2 circle but that gives me only 90 degrees and not more.

Is there any other command I can try to get an scaled extrusion as seen on the screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly extrusion, but it may bring you in the right direction:

1. Create a curve, for instance a circle curve with one segment removed, which gets you a three-quarter circle with 4 control points.
2. Give each control point of the curve a suitable radius, say radius one for the first, radius 2 for the second, ..., radius 4 for the last.
3. In the curve properties, under geometry, set the bevel to anything you like

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this tip.
Stupid question as I never worked with curves. How to remove a segment?
Coz when I draw a bazier circle and in edit mode remove 1 segment or vertice it does not remove the segment (circle is still closed) :-( sorry for being noob!!)

Comment: Got it already :-)